# What is the big difference between including files and using SPL Autoloader.

Tags: php, class, autoload, spl

I'm trying to start using SPL Autoloader but I can't seem to grasp its importance yet.

Lets say I have a directory "classes" with sub-directories and php files in them as classes as follows.

```
'classes/feed/feed.php';
'classes/compose/file_upload.php';
'classes/compose/char_limit.php';
'classes/feed/postrank/postrank.php';
'classes/notifications/push.php';
```

Then I create a PHP file called autoloader.php inside "classes" directory with includes as follows

```
<?php 

    include_once 'feed/feed.php';
    include_once 'compose/file_upload.php';
    include_once 'compose/char_limit.php';
    include_once 'feed/postrank/postrank.php';
    include_once 'notifications/push.php';

    ?>
```

Then on every page where I want those classes I just include the autoloader.php file to include all classes of the project.

**1. What problems I'm I going to face as the project grows?**

**2. If I were to start using SPL Autoloader how would I set it up with my current directory structure?**

**3. Is there a difference in loading time between using include/require compared to SPL Autoloading ?**

**4. Should all the classes be under one directory "classes?" or there's no problem with my file structure?**

Comment: It's kind of similar in concept to dynamic link library. Something to include what files when needed as opposed to include everything all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What problems I'm I going to face as the project grows?**

You'll have to include more and more files in your autoloader.php. Plus, you'll have to include it in your every new file. More file reads. Less performance.

**2. If I were to start using SPL Autoloader how would I set it up with my current directory structure?**

Directory structure doesn't matter (assuming your classes tree is arranged nicely and logically). What matters is the namespace you specify inside your class. For example, if you want SPL to auto-load a class containing in your classes/feed/postrank/postrank.php file (a `postrank` class declaration, presumably), this file has to have a namespace declaration inside it, e.g.:

```
namespace classes\feed\postrank;
class postrank {
    ...
}
```

This way SPL would know how to find the declaration of the class in your application's file system.

**3. Is there a difference in loading time between using include/require compared to SPL Autoloading ?**

If you include everything in autoloader.php, you force PHP to read and include *every single file* in there. SPL only loads the classes you need, and only when you need them. The time difference could be noticeable if you have a decent number of files and classes (say, hundreds of them), depending on your application server performance.

**4. Should all the classes be under one directory "classes?" or there's no problem with my file structure?**

Depends on your application structure really, so it's entirely your call.

Comment: Ok thanks for this. Can you expatiate more on no.2? Am I going to include the auto-loader function on every page? How does the function detect that I want to use a particular class and only load that specific one without loading all the classes.

Comment: You have to use the [spl_autoload()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) function. It can be either used at the beginning of every file you want to run on your server, or take a better path and make only a single entry point to your application, utilizing (for example) an MVC approach. I can't dig into more details here without writing a small article, but I'm sure you'll be able to find more info based on my suggestions.